# variable type validation in typescript not working

Tags: angular, typescript

I am new to typescript, i wrote code like below

```
export class RmdRequest {
    public amount: string;
    public age: number;
}
```

in my form i have like

in my component i have like below

```
 onSubmit(formValues:RmdRequest){ }
```

formValues is a object like below

```
{amount: 20, age: "Super Hot"}
```

If you see amount i have declared as string but passing as int. I was expecting this to throw out error of some sort. Am i doing something wrong for validation?

Comment: `amount` is a `ngModel` of a textbox??

Comment: Yup. I can block it at form level. But the above code should break right? or am i doing something wrong?

Comment: What happens when you're submitting it?

Comment: No error. It goes ahead and makes a service call. Which should not happen ideally.

Comment: Is amount really a number then? If it is coming from a textbox, it will be a string.

Comment: @DeborahK - Yes then also no errors or breaks. So that's my question, where do we use this kind of type checking?

Answer (score 2):

The types you add compile-time only and are erased by the TypeScript compiler at runtime so no type-checking is enforced at runtime. Here's what your code method looks like at runtime after compilation:

```
onSubmit(formValues) {
}
```

If you want to do actual validation on your form inputs, there are many options listed in the [official documentation.](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation)

Comment: I have done that. Say different scenario where in i need to validate the response coming from REST api with above method. Is that also not possible??

Comment: Not possible with TypeScript. You can only do compile-time type checking with TypeScript.

Comment: https://offering.solutions/blog/articles/2016/02/01/consuming-a-rest-api-with-angular-http-service-in-typescript/   Here if u see public Update = (id: number, itemToUpdate: MyTypedItem)  itemToUpdate type checking does not happen at all?

Comment: Learn what? TypeScript? The [official documentation](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/home.html) would be a good place to start.

Comment: In your example, the `itemToUpdate` param will be validated only at compile time, but there is no guarantee that `itemToUpdate` will be of `MyTypedItem` at runtime.